# Counting nodes in a Tree

Tags: recursion, f#, tree, continuations

fighting with f# - the fight is in the realm of Trees - specifically to count the number of nodes.  This is of real interest as the program I would like to eventually code in F# concerns multi-way trees, unfortunately it has got off to a bit of a troublesome start - I hope you maybe able to help!

Problem 61 of the 99 f# series, asks to count the leaves of a binary Tree. The solution (given below) counts the nodes, but my problem is not understanding

- how the double recursion works loop left (fun lacc -> loop right..)
- what `cont (branchF x lacc racc)` is, my impression was that cont was the "abc" function, but this takes only two parameters...
- `loop t id` the id is of type unit - i don't see how this is implied

basically not understanding this, or the order in which it flows through the tree (debug & step through not proving helpful) If there are simpler examples, pre-reading recommendations etc. then please direct me to them.

Many thanks for any help, the solution code in question is below:

Cheers

td

```
type 'a Tree = Empty | Branch of 'a * 'a Tree * 'a Tree

let foldTree branchF emptyV t =
    let rec loop t cont =
        match t with
        | Empty ->
            cont emptyV
        | Branch (x, left, right) ->
            loop left  (fun lacc -> 
                loop right (fun racc ->
                    cont (branchF x lacc racc)))
    loop t id

let counLeaves tree =
    foldTree (fun abc lc rc ->
        if lc + rc = 0 then 1
        else 1 + lc + rc) 0 tree

let Tree1 = Branch ('x', Branch ('x', Empty, Empty),Branch ('x', Empty, Branch ('x', Empty, Branch ('x', Empty, Empty))))


let result = counLeaves Tree1
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the solution, but but Lee is wright and the "if" in counLeaves doesn't do anything. The solution should be let counLeaves tree = tree |> foldTree (fun _ lc rc -> 1 + lc + rc) 0. If you want to know more about folds and continuations. I recommend the series on Catamorphisms by Brian McNamara here [link](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/05/catamorphisms-part-one/). That is where I got the fodlTree function.

Comment: Hi Cesar, just wanted to say thank you for posting the 99 problems series - really great learning tool - particularly the multiple solutions. Cheers!

Comment: Seeing as nobody answered your question about id, "id" is the identity operator.  You can replace id with (fun x -> x) for the same affect. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353607.aspx Also, there's something terribly wrong with this code - I created a simple 4 node tree and it told me the size was 32!  I'll post a correct implementation (which I have working) once I figure out all the nuances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the name implies, `foldTree` defines the fold function over the custom `Tree` type.

A naive way of defining a `foldTree` could be:

```
let rec foldTreeNaive accFun init = function
    | Empty -> init
    | Branch (x, left, right) ->
        let lacc = foldTreeNaive accFun init left
        let racc = foldTreeNaive accFun init right
        accFun x lacc racc
```

The problem with this function is that it could potential make very deep recursive calls if the tree being folded over is deep, since the recursive calls must complete for a node before the accumulator function can be called. For example the following causes a stack overflow exception:

```
let unbalanced = [1..100000] |> List.fold (fun t i -> Branch(i, t, Empty)) Empty
let nodeCount = foldTreeNaive (fun _ lc rc -> lc + rc + 1) 0 unbalanced
```

The usual way to avoid such stack overflows is to make the function tail recursive, however this seems impossible in this case since there are two recursive calls to make, instead of the one required when folding over lists.

`foldTree` is defined using the local `loop` function. This function is interesting in that it is defined using [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). In CPS, each function takes an additional 'continuation' function which is passed the result of the computation and is responsible for deciding what happens next. Note that `loop` is tail recursive and so avoids the overflow problem of `foldTreeNaive`.

The type of the `loop` function is:

```
Tree<'a> -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'c
```

where 'a is the type of nodes in the tree, 'b is the accumulator type, and 'c is the result of the continuation function.

In the case of a leaf node, the continuation is passed the empty accumulator value passed to the `foldTree` function.

When folding over a non-empty tree in the `Branch` case, the result of the fold depends on the results for the left and right subtrees. This is done recursively, first by folding over the left subtree, then the right. For the recursive call over the left subtree, `loop` must build a new continuation to receive the result, this is the

```
(fun lacc -> 
    loop right (fun racc ->
        cont (branchF x lacc racc))
```

function. What this continuation does is to make a recursive call over the right subtree, passing yet another continuation to receive the result of that fold. When that continuation is called, the results for the left and right subtrees are available in `lacc` and `racc`. At this point the accumulation function for the node can be called with the value for the current node and the results for the left and right subtrees. The result of this function is then passed to the original continuation passed to `loop`.

The `loop` function is then invoked by the `foldTree` function in the line:

```
loop t id
```

Here, `id` is the continuation which will receive the result of the fold for the root node of the tree. Since this is the value required, `id` just returns its argument without modification.

You might also find [this description of fold for binary trees](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/) useful.